# Open php file from different php file independently while working with api

Tags: php, api, paypal

Ok so i have a script with 2 different API.

I have a file let call it paypal.php, that file work with paypal api.

When someone place an order on my website and pay with paypal the file paypal.php running and sending my email with the info about the order.
Now after sending the email the paypal.php open different file that work with different API that create invoices.

I am using the file_get_contents commend to open the other php

```
file_get_contents($page_url, false);
```

on the file that is getting opened while using file_get_contents i am transferring data to the invoice website api. And then i wait 60 second and i am using sleep() function to do that. After the 60 second are pass i download the invoices.

Now here my problem, the first file paypal.php seems to wait the 60 second as well. Because of the wait paypal API seems to think the server didn't respond and it running the api again and causing me problems like sending the same email twice and creating the invoice twice.

What i want to do is to open the invoice api independently without harming the paypal.php file.

I have tried few things without success. First i have tried to use this code while using sleep

```
ob_flush();

flush();

sleep(60);
```

And it didn't worked out. I have also tried to run this commend before loading the other file, to try and say to the API is was successful but it didn't work out as well.

```
header( "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" );
```

before loading the invoice file but it didn't worked out as well.

I have ended up changing the sleep commend to 10 second instead of 60 and that seems to work fine but i rather have it as 60 second to be on the safe side.

Does anyone have an idea what can i do to make it work? is there a way to load the invoice file independently without effecting the paypal.php?

Answer (score 0):

If the file exists on your server, than you can use an `include()` statement to run the code in your invoice file. Just add:

```
include('/path/to/your/invoice/file');
```

Wherever you need it to start running.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if i use include() the page load will still take 60 seconds so it won't fix the problem. Also if i am going on include the file some way i want to do it independently and that not something include() offer.